# How not to lose copied elements in setdiff in R?

Tags: r, set-difference

I am using `setdiff` function to extract elements of first set that are not in the other set. But after evaluating `setdiff` I receive such elements but they are single values (not such many as there were in first set); like this:

```
> setdiff( c("x", "x", "y"), c("y"))
[1] "x"
```

Is there a smarter way to extract such elements but in an amount that there were in a first set such as a result of this line?

```
> c("x","x","y")[ c("x","x","y") %in% setdiff( c("x", "x", "y"), c("y"))]
[1] "x" "x"
```

Answer (score 3):

Invert the match for `%in%` to make the expression simpler, and leave `setdiff` behind:

```
> x <- c("x","x","y")
> x
[1] "x" "x" "y"
> x[!x %in% c("y")]
[1] "x" "x"
```